# What's the meaning of "mad" in "Dragon liver, seventeen Sickles an ounce, they're mad!"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A plump woman outside an Apothecary was shaking her head as
>   they passed, saying, "Dragon liver, seventeen Sickles an ounce, they're
>   **mad**...."

What's the meaning of "mad" here?

Oxford definitions of mad:

> 4 *US informal* Great; remarkable.
>
> 2.1 *British* Very exciting.

Since the text is British, the first option is ruled out, but the second option does not make sense too. What does it mean for a liver to be exciting?

Comment: It's neither of these; it's the primary sense of the word, "insane": *They're insane to charge that much."

Comment: @StoneyB: I don't understand. What does it mean for a liver to be mentally ill?! In my mind, mentally ill is applied to humans, not objects.

Comment: @Diamond: From context, it would be the shopkeepers at the Apothecary are mad/insane.  I'm not sure it means "they're insane to charge that _much_". Dragons in fiction are hard to kill. The meaning might be "they're insane to charge _so little_".

Comment: The sentence is perhaps in conversational speech. In any case, dragon liver is not called mad. Whoever in the Apothecary is selling dragon liver are charging seventeen Sickles for an ounce. The person selling the dragon liver at such exorbitant/cheap (depending on the perception of the speaker) price is called 'mad' or 'insane'.

Comment: @MSalters: wouldn't we expect to see "*only* 17 an ounce" in that case?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I don't think it is needed to mention "only" for conveying that the price is insanely low.

Comment: It is the intonation that decides whether it is expensive or cheap.

Comment: @Diamond: People universally complain about high prices; exclaiming that a price is exceptionally low by calling it **mad** would be the exception to the general rule. So, no, **only** is not "needed", but I would say that unless the passage (or context) otherwise makes clear that it is a surprisingly low sum, **only** is to be *expected*.

Comment: @Diamond The value of wizard currency in the Potterverse is inconsistent and controversial. 17 sickles (1 galleon) has been estimated to be equivalent to something between £3-£5 and ten times that much. At $1.60 to the £ and 16oz/lb,  17sickles/oz represented $80-$1200/lb in 1997 dollars.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: At least, this is not the case in my native language, Persian. We convey our intended meaning by the intonation we use, and most of the time, we eliminate *only*.

Comment: @Diamond: We're talking about a text here, not about a live conversation. You'll note that I said "passage (or context)". English uses intonation as well, but I can't think of any intonation where we could clearly make it known (to someone who doesn't know the going price of Dragon liver) that we think it is a madly *low* price and not a madly *high* price, merely by the way we say "they're mad".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: I mean the intonation of saying "seventeen Sickles an ounce," not "they're mad."

Answer (score 3):

*Mad* is often used to mean *angry* but an older meaning of the word is *insane* or *crazy*.  Using this older meaning sounds somewhat literary and can be used to impart a mood of medieval times.

If someone says something that doesn't make sense, but they do not realize it doesn't make sense, then calling them crazy, or mad, is warranted.

> Dragon liver, seventeen Sickles an ounce, they're mad!

The *they* in this sentence does not refer to "Dragon liver", but rather the people/persons who set that price at the shop.  It's possible to use *they* to refer to an indefinite group of people in this way - especially if you want to blame someone at a place but don't really know precisely where to place that blame yet.

Comment: Yes, I understood from the comments above that "they" refers to the persons selling them. At first, I thought the woman is promoting them so that people go inside the shop and buy them. Wouldn't that have been better if the author had used question mark (plus exclamation mark (?!)) after "Sickles" instead of comma?

Comment: I don't think using mad like this makes it sound literary or "oldy-worldy" - I think it is just a British thing. To me (as a Brit) it obviously means crazy, and I wouldn't find it odd for someone to say that to me.